# Get multiple attributes of the same type in the MetadataProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, metadata, custom-attributes

I have a attribute, that has `AllowMultiple`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AllowedDeviceTypesAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    //...
}
```

And I am using it on my Property multiple times:

```
[AllowedDeviceTypes(DeviceTypes.StaticRegister)]
[AllowedDeviceTypes(DeviceTypes.MobileRegister)]
public int ClientNr { get; set; }
```

I have a Custom Model Metadata Provider:

```
public class ExtendedModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<System.Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var attributeList = attributes as IList<System.Attribute> ?? attributes.ToList();
        var data = base.CreateMetadata(attributeList, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        //...
        var allowedDeviceTypesAttributes = attributeList.Where(a => typeof(AllowedDeviceTypesAttribute) == a.GetType()).ToList();
        if (allowedDeviceTypesAttributes.Count > 0)
        {
            var allowedDeviceTypes = allowedDeviceTypesAttributes.Cast<AllowedDeviceTypesAttribute>().Select(e => e.AllowedDeviceType).ToList();
            data.AdditionalValues.Add(AllowedDeviceTypesAttribute.AdditionalMetaDataValue, allowedDeviceTypes);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

My problem is, I always have only a single `AllowedDeviceTypesAttribute` in `attributes`:

[image]

How can I get both attributes?

```
[AllowedDeviceTypes(DeviceTypes.StaticRegister)]
[AllowedDeviceTypes(DeviceTypes.MobileRegister)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, we need to override the `TypeId` Property:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AllowedDeviceTypesAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    //...
    public override object TypeId
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```